# Excel VBA performance of worksheetfunction vs code, for arrays

Tags: excel, vba, performance, excel-2016

In a quest to speed up my VBA code I searched for methods online. A lot of methods pass by, and one of them that keeps returning seems to be *to use worksheetfunctions in stead of code*, where possible.

My experience however is contrary to that tip. I find that *worksheetfunctions tend to be slower than my code*. My simple test below shows that the code is about twice faster than the worksheetfunction. I found the same results with other functions, like MATCH.

My question is then, do you VBA'ers tend to use code or worksheetfunctions? Are there reasons to use the functions over code (besides the couple of lines of extra code)?

```
Sub testSum()

    Dim testarray(0 To 10000) As Variant
    Dim val As Variant
    Dim valSum As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim t As Single

    ' create testarray
    For i = 0 To 10000
        testarray(i) = Rnd
    Next
    For i = 0 To 10000 Step 100
        testarray(i) = "text"
    Next

    ' measure code
    t = Timer
    For j = 1 To 10000
        valSum = 0
        For Each val In testarray
            If IsNumeric(val) Then valSum = valSum + val
        Next
    Next
    Debug.Print "Array: ", Int(valSum), Timer - t

    ' measure function
    t = Timer
    For j = 1 To 10000
        valSum = 0
        valSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(testarray)
    Next
    Debug.Print "Sum: ", Int(valSum), Timer - t

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe they mean *it's faster to **write code** with worksheet functions.*

Comment: worksheet functions are always slower, at least for my experience... I try to use arrays and if i want to sum just arr = arr + new value... This is always faster than doing some application.function

Comment: @Pspl The code above is just a test for performance. I do two things 10k times and than compare the time it takes. Otherwise the difference is not measurable

Comment: @Joost, you are right. Already deleted my answer! I didn't see The `For...Each` inside the first `For...Next`.

Comment: @Joost don't forget to sort both arrays from a to z (or vise versa), then looping will be faster, as you can leave a marker of the last position of the match, and reduce the cycle-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to use the worksheet function in the worksheet. Measuring the function in the macro is an unfair test as the VBA environment must switch to the Excel environment to get the results and this adds an overhead that does not exist otherwise.

As a general coding rule, my priorities are:

- use Native Excel formulas, including setting up helper cells or
  columns.
- use VBA with arrays
- use VBA with ranges

As a test:

- set up 10,000 rows with random numbers
- set up your formula in one cell (`B1`) `=Sum(A1:A10000)`
- select `B1` and calculate the cell

Set up a macro - the below is a quick and dirty based on your code above - it could be neater by using properly qualified ranges and `Option Explicit`.

```
Sub TestNativeSpeed()
    Dim j As Long
    Dim t As Single
    t = Timer
    For j = 1 To 10000
        Range("B1").Dirty
    Next
    Debug.Print "Native Sum: ", Int(Range("B1").Value), Timer - t
End Sub
```

I set up my cells with the formula `=Rand()` and I got the results (single run only):

> Native Sum:    4990          16.53125

I reset them to values only (consistent with your code) and I got the results (single run only):

> Native Sum:    4990          1.765625

I ran your code and got (single run only):

> Array:         4917          4.386719
>
> Sum:           4917          27.73438

What the above shows is that Native Excel is usually the fastest and most efficient approach. But arrays (where it doesn't have to keep switching between the VBA and Excel models) are the next in line in terms of efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I almost exclusively use code.

It's probably an issue, but I hate using functions because I find that I always have to go back and edit bits and it just gets confusing, where I can just mess around with one `Sub` if I'm using code.

To answer your code, I would likely say just use arrays to sum - that'll shed a few picoSeconds

Try and use [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get those brainiacs to improve on your speeds

Comment: You are right that it is just about picoseconds. Who cares. Although when I recently compared two 5k arrays, which amounted into 25m actions, even the picos started to count.
Thanks for pointing me to Code Review. Didn't know that

Comment: Give me a link to your Code Review post if you make one - interested to see what they can do

Comment: Would my question above be a Code Review question?

Comment: If you want a method to make this quicker - yeah. If you're just asking people their opinion, I guess it can stay here - but over there they can solve your issues and tell you why it's quicker - sort of a double whammy?